# How to merge 4 Audio and 1 Video .MXF files in to one h.264 video file on Linux using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mxf

On a recent video shoot, the camera man gave us output as .MXF files. Incidentally, Audio and Video are saved in separate .mxf files. 

eg:
0007WA00.MXF - Audio  ([probe](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Hqrmwk6rf4/))
0007WA01.MXF - Audio  ([probe](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HnbFRZsFyR/))
0007WA02.MXF - Audio  ([probe](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WSvH7gZSFq/))
0007WA03.MXF - Audio  ([probe](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y5MQRTfzbq/))
0007WA.MXF - Video  ([probe](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/D7jXN4bgJT/))

I am trying to figure out how to merge these in to a single video file. So far I couldn't find a way out.

[Edit: 20 Jun 2019]
I managed to get audio and video stitched. However, audio is mono. Want a little clarity on whether I can have stereo or surround by utilizing the 4 audio files.

Command that worked:

```
ffmpeg -i 0007WA.MXF -i 0007WA00.MXF -i 0007WA01.MXF -i 0007WA02.MXF -i 0007WA03.MXF -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental ../ffmpeg-stitch-mxf.mp4
```

*Let me add that I am not an expert at this. Perhaps some may find my questions naive.*

Comment: What command did you try?

Comment: ffmpeg -i 0007WA.MXF -i 0007WA00.MXF -i 0007WA01.MXF -i 0007WA02.MXF -i 0007WA03.MXF -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental ../ffmpeg-stitch-mxf.mxf

Comment: that didn't work. However, gonna re-try with video codec too. Let's see if that works!

Comment: added an edit to the question.

Comment: Do you want to open the merged file in a professional video editor?

Comment: So the audio is 4 channels and they are supposed to play over the 1 video stream?  Seems that way, since they are all the same length, but just want to be clear. Gyan asks an important question: What do you want to do with the resultant file (e.g. post to YT, open in a editor for further processing, etc.)?

Comment: A follow up on the audio channels: Are all of them actually used? I find that most times, only 1 or 2 channels are used. Can you verify that all files have content that you want?

Comment: You probably need to look into the `-map` flag to get what you want. See this related question: [ffmpeg - mapping an audio file with 2 channels to a video file?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18738/ffmpeg-mapping-an-audio-file-with-2-channels-to-a-video-file)

Comment: Q: So the audio is 4 channels and they are supposed to play over the 1 video stream >> A: Yes |  Q: Gyan asks an important question: What do you want to do with the resultant file >> A: Eventually to Web. But, a video editor will process it before uploading. Processing = adding watermark, text, cut-n-merge etc.

Comment: Addon-Q: Why look at ffmpeg when there is a video editor? >> A: Video editor wants a format he/she can work with. The Panasonic camera for some reason recorded in MXF and with audio separate from video (courtesy camera man). Me, a Linux user is exploring solution to the given problem.

Comment: Suggestion: You probably need to look into the -map flag to get what you want. >> Reply:  That is what I did eventually. I wanted to post that as an answer, but I waited to see if some one gives a better solution. I used only two audio files in the merge. |  I think I should post that as an answer and let community enhance it, if there is scope.

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -i 0007WA.MXF -i 0007WA00.MXF -i 0007WA01.MXF -i 0007WA02.MXF -i 0007WA03.MXF -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 -c copy merged.mov` to generate a file for the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I used ffmpeg with only '-i' switch to figure out which stream was audio and which was video. Then executed the following to merge two audio channels and its video.

```
ffmpeg -i 0007WA.MXF -i 0007WA00.MXF -i 0007WA01.MXF -filter_complex "[1:0] [2:0] amerge" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -qscale 0 -y  ../ffmpeg-att2.mp4
```

I think there can be more options by utilizing all four audio files to make stereo or surround. However, I stopped here as the output was acceptable. 
Note - used '-qscale 0'  to limit quality-loss.